# findMany is not a function in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, backend

I was making a commenting system on my website. I stored all the comment data in MongoDB and now I abviously need to access that data to print out the comments to a user. But, I see that there is no 'findMany' function for the collection object. I just need to get all the code in the collection in an array. findOne finds one document, then findMany should be there right? Is there any other such function in the collection object which can give me all the data in a collection of a database in MongoDB

Any help would be great!

Comment: there is no any findMany function, you can use `find` function.

Comment: This seems like you could have easily gotten this from [reading the documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.7/classes/Collection.html).

Comment: But the 'find' function is returning something gibberish

Comment: you need to use toArray method after that `find().toArray()`

Comment: wait, I will try

Comment: It worked! The find().toArray() method actually worked, thank you so much turivishal

Comment: The `collection.find` method returns a _cursor_. The cursor has many methods to read and work with data returned by the find.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the find().toArray() method instead of findMany({ }) to get all the data there in the collection and to keep that data in an array. This will give you an array with all the data in the collection.